ABAP Program: Append the content of two binary files into one file
In my ABAP program, I have the content of two binary files of the same type as XSTRING.
Binary files such as: docx, xlsx, pptx, pdf, etc.
I need to append these two files content to another file of the same type.
e.g. join two PDF files into another PDF file.
Problem is:
The final file contains only the content of the first file, although the file size equals the sum of both file sizes.
In debugger looks everything fine! the concatenation looks correct too!
What I did:

Convert each XSTRING content to binary data tab.
Append the content of each table to third binary data tab.
Download as binary file.

Here is my code:
        DATA: lt_bin_old  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF x255.
        DATA: lt_bin_new  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF x255.
        DATA: lt_bin      TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF x255.

        CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
          EXPORTING
            buffer        = <lv_old_value>
          IMPORTING
            output_length = lv_size
          TABLES
            binary_tab    = lt_bin_old.

        CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
          EXPORTING
            buffer          = <lv_new_value>
          IMPORTING
            output_length   = lv_size2
          TABLES
            binary_tab      = lt_bin_new.

        lv_size = lv_size + lv_size2.
        APPEND LINES OF lt_bin_old TO lt_bin.
        APPEND LINES OF lt_bin_new TO lt_bin.
      
      cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download(
        EXPORTING
          bin_filesize              = lv_size
          filename                  = lv_fullpath
          filetype                  = 'BIN'
        CHANGING
          data_tab                  = lt_bin
        EXCEPTIONS
          file_write_error          = 1
          no_batch                  = 2
          gui_refuse_filetransfer   = 3
          invalid_type              = 4
          no_authority              = 5
          unknown_error             = 6
          header_not_allowed        = 7
          separator_not_allowed     = 8
          filesize_not_allowed      = 9
          header_too_long           = 10
          dp_error_create           = 11
          dp_error_send             = 12
          dp_error_write            = 13
          unknown_dp_error          = 14
          access_denied             = 15
          dp_out_of_memory          = 16
          disk_full                 = 17
          dp_timeout                = 18
          file_not_found            = 19
          dataprovider_exception    = 20
          control_flush_error       = 21
          not_supported_by_gui      = 22
          error_no_gui              = 23
          OTHERS                    = 24
      ).
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        RETURN.
      ENDIF.

What I tried also:

Concatenate two XSTRING values.
Convert the result to binary data tab.
Download as binary file.

        CONCATENATE <lv_old_value> <lv_new_value> INTO <lv_value> IN BYTE MODE.

        CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_BINARY_TO_XSTRING'
          EXPORTING
            input_length = lv_size
          IMPORTING
            buffer       = <lv_value>
          TABLES
            binary_tab   = lt_bin
          EXCEPTIONS
            failed       = 1
            OTHERS       = 2.
        IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        ENDIF.

       cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download(
        EXPORTING
          bin_filesize              = lv_size
          filename                  = lv_fullpath
          filetype                  = 'BIN'
        CHANGING
          data_tab                  = lt_bin
        EXCEPTIONS
          file_write_error          = 1
          no_batch                  = 2
          gui_refuse_filetransfer   = 3
          invalid_type              = 4
          no_authority              = 5
          unknown_error             = 6
          header_not_allowed        = 7
          separator_not_allowed     = 8
          filesize_not_allowed      = 9
          header_too_long           = 10
          dp_error_create           = 11
          dp_error_send             = 12
          dp_error_write            = 13
          unknown_dp_error          = 14
          access_denied             = 15
          dp_out_of_memory          = 16
          disk_full                 = 17
          dp_timeout                = 18
          file_not_found            = 19
          dataprovider_exception    = 20
          control_flush_error       = 21
          not_supported_by_gui      = 22
          error_no_gui              = 23
          OTHERS                    = 24
      ).
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        RETURN.
      ENDIF.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Why do you want to append them? What is your goal? Is it to have a single file that displays content of both or would having a container (like ZIP) to hold 2 files solve your problem?
If it's the former, I suggest you look into parsing and appending content of specific file formats and not binary. Fred gave you a good pointer. Another consideration is limiting file input to PDF, which would reduce your workload. Most documents can be converted to PDF.

You can't concatenate two xstring variables to create a new file. It doesn't work like this.
But you can merge two PDF files to a new one using the class below:
TRY .
    DATA(lo_merger) = NEW cl_rspo_pdf_merge( ).

  CATCH cx_rspo_pdf_merge INTO DATA(lo_error).

    "Error handling

ENDTRY. 

lo_merger->check_document( EXPORTING document   = lv_pdf_xstring1
                           IMPORTING error_text = DATA(error_text)
                                     rc         = DATA(lv_subrc) ).

IF lv_subrc NE 0 .
  "Error handling
ENDIF.

lo_merger->add_document( lv_pdf_xstring1 ).

lo_merger->check_document( EXPORTING document   = lv_pdf_xstring2
                           IMPORTING error_text = error_text
                                     rc         = lv_subrc ).

IF lv_subrc NE 0 .
  "Error handling
ENDIF.

lo_merger->add_document( lv_pdf_xstring2 ).

lo_merger->merge_documents( IMPORTING merged_document = DATA(lv_pdf_xstring_result)
                                      rc              = lv_subrc ).

The two xstring variables lv_pdf_xstring1 and lv_pdf_xstring2 are the source and lv_pdf_xstring_result will be the result.
I hope this helps
:)
pdf

Thanks for your answer.
The problem hier is: ur solution can only work with pdf files but in runtime i dont' have any idea what the file extension is!
I only know it is a binary file; it could be a PDF, XLSX, PPTX and etc..
How can i solve it ?!

There is no catch all for all file types. Different files are structured differently, So you have to implement the merge for each file type seperately.

What is this link "pdf" for? (link to all PDF questions) An error? No need to indicate this very general link, the OP can search by himself.

We had the same problem with a set of files having different extensions. We couldn't zip them, by user request.
Our solution was to use a java library that allowed to convert from office & image file to pdf (there are several that can do this). With this, we created a small WebService that took a set of file, loaded them as pdf and concatenated/merged them, returning the concatenated file.

Adding the pages/content of one document to the end another one can be called concatenating. Yes it is also known as "merging". But I think it is clear that I'm not speakink of adding the binaries one after the other.

Nice and detailled answer.
In my case, the files can also be office and images in addition to PDF. So having a library that can open a a word doc and add the pages to the final PDF is making for easy maintenance. The library also take care of the page order, so code is quite simple. We also use it to generate a set of bookmark in the final file
